# php random number with number(1-9) only 6 length

Tags: php

I want only 6 random numbers `[length = 6]` from `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` in `php` function without duplicates.

This is my code

```
$a = mt_rand(1,9999999999); //because I need from 1 to 9999999999 of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
for ($i = 0; $i<6; $i++) 
{
   $a .= mt_rand(0,9);
}
```

I am not sure my code is good solution or not

How I can do it?

Comment: Store them in an array, shuffle it, get the first 6 values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
function GenerateRandom($min, $max, $range) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $range);
}

print_r( GenerateRandom(0,25,6) );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your source array is rather big, you may save some memory by only fetching what you need:

```
$a = range(0, 9);

for ($i = 0, $n = count($a); $i < 6 && --$n; ++$i) {
    $r = mt_rand(0, $n);
    if ($r != $n) {
        $tmp = $a[$n];
        $a[$n] = $a[$r];
        $a[$r] = $tmp;
    }
}

echo join(',', array_slice($a, -6));
```

I'm coining the term "Partial Knuth Shuffle" for this.